# create partition inside Linux Mint to install Windows 7

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot

I have installed 64-bit Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon on my laptop, which has no other OS. Right now Mint uses the entire hard disk.

Is it possible to create a partition from Mint for Windows 7? (Windows 7 must be able to see this partition during its installation process. have created a partition before, but Windows couldn't recognize it.)

Comment: No, you have to reduce the size of the Linux partition and create a new (primary) partition for Windows in the free space. Search for according questions here, there are many.

Comment: can i reduce the size of Linux partition from Linux OS?

Comment: That would be possible but the more interesting part is how to reduce the file system in the partition first. The usual procedure is to boot a Linux which does not access the respective partition and make the changes from there. In your case that means that you have to boot from a different device (CD/DVD/USB). IIRC there is even a special partition manipulation Linux for the usage from CD/USB.

Comment: you mean, i can boot from a live USB, do the partition, then will be able to install windows on the new partition? would it be easier/safer (i am new to this) to just re-install mint and do the partition during the installation process?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I converted your answer to a comment since it was not actually answering the question but just telling the OP to go find a guide.

Comment: Suggestion: Run Windows in a virtual machine.

Answer (score -1):

I have not yet found a direct way to solve this using inbuilt methods in Linux Cinnamon that did not require installing other software (GParted).

I solved this by starting to install a new copy of Linux from a Live CD. This gave me the option to format the existing Drive. In choosing how to install, I chose "Something else" other options were "Erasing the existing.."

I then created a new partition on the Primary drive and choose the extension Fat32 (Windows can read this). I unchecked formatting the drive because I want to keep my Linux Rebecca. It took a while to create the partition. when it was through I broke off the installation process and remained with an extra Fat32 partition.

There must be some easier way, but this saved me hours of googling...